# Posting to Hubot via Curl

Tags: heroku, hubot

I'm running Hubot on Heroku and have connected it to Hipchat.

I'd now like to use Curl to post third-party information to the Hubot, when appropriate.

There are two scripts that seem the right fit, **[http-post-say.coffee](https://github.com/github/hubot-scripts/blob/master/src/scripts/http-post-say.coffee)** or **[http-say.coffee](https://github.com/github/hubot-scripts/blob/master/src/scripts/http-say.coffee)**. I can't get either to work.

*http-post-say* points to port 8080, which I don't believe will work on Heroku, and *http-say* simply doesn't post, without any error message.

Both scripts have zero config, and I've successfully deployed several other scripts, so I'm at a loss.

Has anyone successfully used either script in the scenario I've described, or taken a different approach to reach the same goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is a bit late.

httpd-post-say just worked for me ignore the port 8080 for heroku just use your app url (app-name.herokuapp.com). The more confusing thing for me was for room you need to use the XMPP JID which looks like 12345_something@conf.hipchat.com. So to post a message it would look as follows for heroku.

```
curl -X POST http://app-name.herokuapp.com/hubot/say -d message='Hello World' -d room='12345_room_name@conf.hipchat.com'
```